# Standard library function for running a function only once

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, c++14

Is there some standard library function/class the behaviour of this lambda expression:

```
void some_func(int some_arg, float some_other_arg){
    static int do_once = ([](){
        // will be run once upon first function call but never again
        return 0; // dummy return value
    })();
    // will always run
}
```

It feels like such a hack to write this, but I can't think of another way of doing this other than simply calling the function in `main`, but what I'm actually doing depends upon template parameters and I need to keep it as generic as possible.

For context:
I register a function with `atexit` for every different template parameter, but only once: the first time it is called.

Comment: maybe std::call_once ? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once

Comment: But then I'm required to keep an `std::once_flag` statically, which doesn't really have an advantage in a single-threaded environment to what I'm already doing.

Comment: You should make your comment an answer, I'd accept it

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Maybe you should use `std::call_once` found in `<mutex>`. 
Examples of how to use it [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once)

Comment: It actually worked out better using the `once_flag` because my function to be run once relied on another part of parent function

Answer (score 2):

I have gone with the `std::call_once` option, and it works great.

To do so I have re-written my function like so:

```
template<typename T>
void my_function(){
    static std::once_flag once;

    // function body (may return)

    // only called if rest of function successful
    std::call_once(once, [](){/* special sauce */});
}
```

@cdhowie, I don't think you quite understand what I mean by `static`, it's almost the opposite of global.

Comment: Indeed I do understand what `static` means in this context, and it actually means a very similar thing when declaring a class member -- it means that there is only one copy of the given member.  This approach is indeed feasible, and so is mine.  Just different approaches to implementing it.  :)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in comments, `std::call_once()` is an option, but you can't make the `std::once_flag` global or only one function would ever get called -- even if you supply different template arguments.  It sounds like you want to call a function only once *for given template arguments.*

If this is the case then you can make the function a static part of a template class, while still using the `std::call_once()` mechanism:

```
template <typename T>
class initializer
{
public:
    static void call();

private:
    static void target();

private:
    static std::once_flag flag;
};

template <typename T>
void initializer<T>::call()
{
    std::call_once(flag, target);
}

template <typename T>
void initializer<T>::target()
{
    // Your code goes here.
}

template <typename T>
std::once_flag initializer<T>::flag;
```

Now you can call `initializer<T>::call()` with different `T` types and you are guaranteed to make no more than one call per distinct `T`.

Comment: A little bit overkill just to store **one** `once_flag` statically

Comment: @CoffeeandCode There is one flag *per distinct instantiation* which is *exactly* the same case as with your answer.  The compiler will instantiate a flag for every distinct `T` in both of our answers.

Comment: yes, I understand your answer entirely; but it's overkill to be defining classes to store one `once_flag` per `T`

Comment: That is entirely possible, except that we do have the possibility to reuse the class with different implementations.  (One could make `target` pure abstract for example.)  In both cases it will get compiled to similar (if not identical) machine code.

Comment: Yeah, I do like to keep my code more generic (as said in question) and it does have the benefit of being able to specialize my `target` function